What is the timing of the first two drum beats

This is a snare only measure taken from 


What are the timings of first two beats? [1-e-&-a-2-e-&-a]
If first two beats are not there,rhythm would be
1-s-&-a 2-s-&-a where s denotes absence of a snare note.
How can I include first two beats here.

Not an exact duplicate, but a similar question: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/126637/multiple-grace-note-snare-drum-ornament The top answer provides a link to this video which addresses the notation you are asking about: https://youtu.be/_OUBBArtteg

By “beats” do you mean strokes?

@ToddWilcox yes

Since this hasn't gotten an answer, and in case the talk of ruffs and so forth doesn't make it clear: "Grace notes" like these don't usually* have an "official" rhythm. They're just "short notes" that happen "in between" the big notes. They're used for exactly that reason; they're either so short that it would be hard and confusing to print them as a "real rhythm," or it doesn't really matter to the composer exactly how many milliseconds they last, just their rough timing in relation to other notes.
For these two grace notes, you could think of them simply as happening "right before" the downbeat. If you're counting "1-e-&-a", or sixteenth notes, that means that they're somewhere "during" the "a." If you want, as a simplified way at first, you could just play them as 32nd notes, splitting the "a" in half, but that is probably a different stick technique from a true ruff, and maybe not a good idea. It's probably best to learn the concept of their timing and the practical technique of their execution at the same time.

* Some ornaments, like the appoggiatura, have a very specific convention of how they're timed that can actually be plotted out nicely using simple counting. But we'll ignore those for this question.
